# Keep keyboard open when navigating to a new page

Tags: flutter

I have an app with two pages - each page contains a textfield and the first page also contains a "Next" button that will navigate to page 2.

My questions is this: When the textfield on page 1 has focus and I push the "Next button" the keyboard will close before navigating to the next screen.

Is there a way to suppress this behaviour so the keyboard will stay open instead of first closing and the opening again when page 2 is shown?

Comment: hi!
did you find an answer? is it possible at all?

Answer (score 4):

You can try

`SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');` for hiding

and `SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show');` for showing keyboard

And it needs to add `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Comment: There are different ways. One of them - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_visibility

Answer (score 1):

You could use a technique similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58906112 .  Specifically, create a `Stack` at the top of your application with a hidden text field.  Focus that text field whenever you need to keep the keyboard visible and navigate between pages.  Example code below.

You will also need a way for widgets on pages to access the hidden widget's `FocusNode` object.  I recommend using [`ScopedModel`](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model).

```dart
class KeepKeyboardOnScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final FocusNode focusNode;

  const KeepKeyboardOnScreen({@required this.focusNode});

  @override
  State createState() => KeepKeyboardOnScreenState();
}

class KeepKeyboardOnScreenState extends State<KeepKeyboardOnScreen> {
  TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
        height: 0,
        child: ClipRect(
          child: CupertinoTextField(
            controller: _controller,
            focusNode: widget.focusNode,
            onChanged: (_) => _controller.clear(),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If `autofocus` is set to true for the TextField in your second page and the keyboard is active prior to hitting the next button in your first page, the keyboard will remain same during the page transition.